# Why use clone() when we can copy object using = operator?

Tags: java

Clone() is used for an exact copy of the object. like this

```
B s2=(B)s1.clone();
```

But we can also copy object using syntax like #

```
B s2=s1;
```

in both scenario output is the same then why do we use clone()?

```
class B {
    int rollno;
    String name;

    B(int rollno,String name) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            B s1 = new B(101, "amit");

            B s2 = (B) s1.clone();

            System.out.println(s1.rollno + " " + s1.name);
            System.out.println(s2.rollno + " " + s2.name);
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException c) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't clone the object:

```
B s2=s1;
```

It simply creates a second variable `s2` that references the same object.

You can see the difference when you try to modify `s2` before printing either one:

```
B s1 = new B(101, "amit");

B s2 = s1;
s2.name="newName";

System.out.println(s1.rollno + " " + s1.name);
System.out.println(s2.rollno + " " + s2.name);
```

This code will print `newName` as the name for both lines, because there's really only one object referenced by two variables.

If you replace `B s2 = s1` with `B s2 = s1.clone()` however, then it'll print two different names, because an actual copy of the object was created.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you write `b1 = b2` you just create another reference to the same object.

```
B b1 = new B();    // b1 is a reference to the B object
B b2 = b1;         // b2 is a new reference to the same B object
B b3 = (B)b1.clone(); // b3 is a reference to the new B object (total two B objects in memory)
```

Answer (score 0):

`s2 = s1` does *not* copy the object. It just points an additional variable at the same object.

If you then do `s1.setFoo("bar")` that will have affected "both" objects (because there is only one object).